# Antdesing TimePicker; onChange method

Tags: reactjs

I use the AntDesign library for my React app. I have found a problem with the TimePicker, which is not yet mentioned on the Internet.
The onChange method is not called.

```
const Comp = () => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');
    const format = 'HH:mm';
    const onCHANGE = () => (time, timeString) => {
        console.log(time, timeString);
    };
    return (
        <TimePicker
            value={moment('00:00', format)}
            format={format}
            onChange={onCHANGE}
        />
    );
};

export default Comp;
```

The onCHANGE function should only execute a simple log, but this does not appear.